# Wicket. How can i get input values from listview textfields

Tags: listview, input, get, wicket

I have this

```
private ArrayList<String> offersParams = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here i create listview with label and textfield by offersParams size

```
        final ListView listview = new ListView("listview", offersParams) {
        public void populateItem(final ListItem item) {


            item.add(new Label("label", item.getModel());
            item.add(offersStringParams = new TextField<>("textField", Model.of(""));
            offersStringParams.setOutputMarkupId(true);


        }
    };
    form.add(listview);
```

This is my html

```
                <tr wicket:id="listview">
                <td class="col-xs-6"><span class="control-label" wicket:id="label">label</span></td>
                <td class="col-xs-6"><input class="form-control" wicket:id="textField" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
```

After i need get all input values from textFields, but i can get only last value by this code

So i need help. Im neewbie in wicket and im dont understand how can i get all input values from textfields. On submit - i need put pair label & input value to JSONObject

**UPD**
This is my submit btn, where inputValue - it is one of input values from text fields

```
        setOffer = new Button("setOffer") {
        @Override
        public void onSubmit() {
            super.onSubmit();
            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();


                for (int a = 0; a < offersParams.size(); a++) {
                    jsonObject.put(offersParams.get(a), inputValue);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let your TextFields write directly into a map like so:

```
private Map<String, String> offersValues = new HashMap<>();

final ListView listview = new ListView("listview", offersParams) {
public void populateItem(final ListItem item) {
    item.add(new Label("label", item.getModel());
    item.add(new TextField<>("textField", new PropertyModel(offersValues, item.getModelObject()));
}
```

In `#onSubmit()` you can just convert the map to a JSONObject:

```
public void onSubmit() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(offersValues);
    ...
}
```

Comment: ohh  thank you man! Its really works! I think about Map, but cant write this construction )

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior and you have to make offersStringParams local.

```
item.add(new Label("label", item.getModel());
final TextField<String> offersStringParams = new TextField<>("textField", Model.of("");
item.add(offersStringParams);
offersStringParams.setOutputMarkupId(true);
offersStringParams.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onsubmit") { 
    @Override 
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
        String value = offersStringParams.getModelObject();
        // do something with the value here
    } 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work as i see,
this construction get null object -
                         String value = offersStringParams.getModelObject();
                        System.out.println(value); // it is - []